# Azure Table Storage, Cassandra or HBase for caching

Tags: cassandra, hbase, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am developing site with a large number of users and contents, so I need to cache some data about their (in format like string key and serialized array or columns - millions rows). I look at Windows Azure Table Storage, Cassandra or HBase.

Plus in Azure Table Storage - scalability and it isn't necessary to think of place on disk, count of folders and files in folders and etc. Minus - I don't understand yet what speed of address to it will be via REST (time of request and response), so it is not locally address to file.

Plus in Cassandra or HBase - so checked systems. Minuses - should be developed and adjusted; I don't understand yet, what productivity should be provided for what size of data and a quantity of requests; will take a large place on a disk with a site (on VM with a site), so it is necessary to watch and scale, but on Azure it (scale VM storage) is not one button.

Please recommend what system to choose and why.

Comment: "caching"? sounds more like storage what you're describing.

Comment: No, I need caching. I do not want to cache in simple files (in VM), because it is difficult to scalable and OS has some restrictions for large quantity of files. So I need to fast save, read and search data from cache.

Comment: Why not memcache or redis?

Comment: Maybe, but now I would like to listen pro and con of using for cache of Azure Table Storage, Cassandra and HBase. Except usual storage and use, I need to do selections by NoSQL queries.

Comment: Did you ever figure out which way to go?  I was thinking of implementing Azure Table Storage for distributed, geo-redundant caching.  Would like to hear from anyone who has done the same.  Our hangup is that the Azure Caching service is still in Preview...